# virtualenv activation on windows

Tags: python, windows-7, path, virtualenv, system-paths

I have installed virtualenv 1.10 on a Windows 7 machine with Python 2.7 on it.

I have created a virtual env called TESTENV. It is located in C:\

If I run `C:\TESTENV\Scripts\activate` and then type `python` followed by:

```
import sys
print sys.prefix
```

it outputs `C:\TESTENV`, as exprected.

But if I run `D:\virtualenv_test.py` (which is a script containing the two lines of code I used above) it outputs `C:\Python27`.

I tried adding a shebang line to the script but that doesn't work on Windows.

Why is the script not running in the context of the virtual environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`virtualenv` doesn't change the default application that starts a file.

When you installed Python, the installation associated `.py` and `.pyw` files with appropriate `C:\Python27\python.exe` and `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe` applications. So when you run (in your cmd) only `D:\virtualenv_test.py`, cmd looks into the registry and finds the application that is associated with `.py` files and then runs the file with that application. In this case that is the previously installed `C:\Python27\python.exe`.

`virtualenv` `activate` only adds that particular virtual environments python interpreter at the start of the `PATH` environment variable, so when you type `python` in `cmd` you will get the appropriate `python.exe` executed.

So the solution to your problem is to run your script as:

```
python D:\virtualenv_test.py
```

After you activated the environment.